# R subtracting 1 month from today's date gives NA

Tags: r, date, subtraction, lubridate, calculation

I have a script in which I subset my data according to some set time periods and wanted to subset all the records that had occurred in the last month.

However if I try to subtract one month from today's date it yields an NA:

```
> today <- Sys.Date()
> today
[1] "2017-03-29"
> today - months(1)
[1] NA
```

I do have lubridate loaded but I think this calculation is being performed with base R.  If I subtract 2 or more months it works fine:

```
> today - months(2)
[1] "2017-01-29"
> today - months(3)
[1] "2016-12-29"
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on?

UPDATE: I think this is something to do with simple date subtraction not handling leap year cases (2017 is not a leap year so `"2017-02-29"` does not exist).

Are there other packages / functions that take into account leap years?  For the above example I would expect the answer to revert to the last day of the previous month, i.e.:

```
today - months(1)
# Should yield:
"2017-02-28"
```

Would it make sense for this calculation to give the same results for both today and yesterday (or what is the ISO convention for this)?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] xlsx_0.5.7         xlsxjars_0.6.1     rJava_0.9-8        MRAtools_0.6.8     stringdist_0.9.4.4 stringr_1.2.0     
 [7] stringi_1.1.3      lubridate_1.6.0    data.table_1.10.4  PKI_0.1-3          base64enc_0.1-3    digest_0.6.12     
[13] getPass_0.1-1      RPostgreSQL_0.5-1  DBI_0.5-1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   rstudioapi_0.6 tools_3.3.2    parallel_3.3.2
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The calculation of months is indeed perfomed by base R but not the way your think. Months is used to get the month of a date object.

```
#Example
today <- Sys.Date()
months(today)
[1] "March"
```

To add or substract months, you should use `%m+%` from `lubridate`:

```
today <- Sys.Date()
today %m+% months(-1)
[1] "2017-02-28"
```

Comment: When using `lubridate`, the `months` function is overwritten and does not function like base R.

Comment: @TARehman No, the lubridate function is `month` with no "s". Base R has `months`

Comment: Base R's `months` function won't take a number, but when I load `lubridate`, I can give `months` a number. Why is that? See also in the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.6.0/topics/quick_periods which seems to suggest it is overriding the base R function.

Comment: I think it's the `%m+%` function that accepts more inputs because `lubridate::months(Sys.Date())` gives an error saying that `months` is not part of lubridate.

Comment: That's genuinely weird, because when `lubridate` is loaded, `months(1)` returns "1m 0d 0H 0M 0S". I'm not a big user of `lubridate`, so really just more for my own information than anything. :)

Comment: @TARehman I agree. Not sure why months(1) works after lubridate is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

One month ago is non-defined in this context. February 29th only exists in leap years.

See the [`lubridate` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.6.0/topics/quick_periods%20lubridate%20Documentation):

> Note: Arithmetic with periods can results in undefined behavior when non-existent dates are involved (such as February 29th in non-leap years). Please see Period-class for more details and %m+% and add_with_rollback for alternative operations.

The `lubridate` package can handle what you are doing, but you need to perform the operaton using `%m+%`.

Comment: Have accepted @P Lapointe's worked answer but +1 for pointing me towards the specific help on this topic in lubridate.

Comment: Updated link - https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/mplus.html