# why months work in one case in R but not in another?

Tags: r

As shown below I am trying to understand why it is NA in one case and not in another.

```
> x<-"2017-10-31"
> as.Date(x) - months(6)
[1] NA
> x<-"2018-07-31"
> as.Date(x) - months(6)
[1] "2018-01-31"
>
```

Comment: Neither 2017 or 2018 is a leap year

Comment: There are only 30 days in April, so it returns NA

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098932/r-subtracting-1-month-from-todays-date-gives-na i.e. `as.Date(x) %m-% months(6)#
[1] "2017-04-30"`

Answer (score 3):

That is because `as.Date("2017-10-31") - months(6)` (exactly) would be 2017-04-**31**, which doesn't exist.

If you want to subtract months without worrying about exceeding the last day of the month (moon calendar now!), use the fantastic functions `%m+%` and `%m-%` from `lubridate` package.

```r
as.Date("2017-10-31") %m-% months(6)

[1] "2017-04-30"
```

For more details, `` ?lubridate::`%m+%` ``

Answer (score 2):

We can use `%m-` from `lubridate` to resolve the issue

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date(x) %m-% months(6)
# [1] "2017-04-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 30 days in April when you attempt to subtract 6 months from October 31st. It returns `NA`.

```
> x <- "2017-10-31"
> as.Date(x) - months(6)
[1] NA
> x <- "2017-10-30"
> as.Date(x) - months(6)
[1] "2017-04-30"
```